# Selenium changes Internet Explorer proxy configuration

Tags: selenium

I'm using `selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar` together with tests written in C# to test my web application.

I'm on a corporate network and in order to access external websites, I need to configure Internet Explorer to use a .pac file:
Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings -> Use automatic configuration script -> `http://proxy.corporateUrl:8080/pacfile.pac`. The web application needs to access external url:s so I have to use this proxy file.

However, when running selenium it sets its own pac file instead, looking something like this:
`file://C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp/2/7e03b3f7bc834b37916053a5c693a02c839069602558458747/proxy.pac`

With the following content:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    return 'PROXY localhost:4444; DIRECT';
}
```

And when this pac file is set, I can no longer access external sites. So, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a .pac file that is served from a local webserver (i.e. http://example.com/proxy.pac ) and isn't on the local disk.